# How to measure number of operations performed

Tags: java, profiling, complexity-theory

In my current project, I am measuring complexity of algorithms written in Java. I operate with asymptotic complexity (expected result) and I want to validate the expectation by comparison with the actual number of operations. Using Incrematation per operation seems to me a bit clumsy awkward. Is there any better approach to measure operational complexity?

Thanks

---

Edit: more info

- The algorithms might run on different machines
- Some parts of divide and conquer algorithms might be precached, hence it is probable, that the procedure will be faster than expected
- Also it is important for me to find out the multiplicative constant (or the additive one), which is not taken in consideration in asymptotic complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an actual computer you want to measure execution time, getCurrentTimeMillis(). Vary the N parameter, get solid statistics. Do an error estimate. Your basic least squares will be fine.

Counting operations on an algorithm is fine, but it has limited use. Different processors do stuff at different speeds.  Counting the number of expressions or statements executed by your implemented algorithm is close to useless. In the algorithm you can use it to make comparisons for tweaking, in your implementation this is no longer the case, compiler/JIT//CPU tricks will dominate.

Asymptotic behavior should be very close to the calculated/expected if you do good measurements.

Comment: The problem is little bit more complex. Because I expect to solve divide and conquer algorithms. And I might have some partial solution pre-cached. So I expect to do much better than asymptotic complexity suggests... And I want to know how better is the actual implemetation with data than the "expected complexity".

Comment: Yep, measure, measure and measure; and don't get your hopes up. You might want to share your D&C in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Is there particular reason not to just measure the CPU time? The time utility or a profiler will get you the numbers. Just run each algorithm with a sufficient range of inputs and capture the cpu time (not wall clock time) spent.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think that's going to be really tough -- you'll end up comparing compiler, vm, os, and processor efficiency in addition to the algorithmic complexity. I would recommend isolating the algorithmic complexity to a single machine first, then expanding the field and comparing again.

Answer (score 1):

[ByCounter](https://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/ByCounter) can be used to instrument Java (across multiple classes) and count the number of bytecodes executed by the JVM at runtime.